# Cannot open source file err.h in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

When I run my program on a mac it works just fine, but when I do it using Visual Studio I get this error:

> Cannot open source file err.h

Is there another way to handle errors in Visual studio or am I not calling  correctly?

```
 #include <err.h>
```

Here's How I'm trying to use err in my code:

```
switch (select(1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tmo)) {
    case -1:
        err(1, "select"); // This throw an error
        break;
    case 0:
        printf("You did not enter your password within 5 seconds\n");
        return (1);
        break;
}
```

Comment: I think `err` is a Linux thing

Comment: @EdHeal do you know how to include it on windows (Visual studio)?

Answer (score 1):

The entire `<err.h>` (with `err()`, `errx()`, `warnx`, etc.) is, actually, a BSD-thing.

[Linux adopted it](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html) - smartly. Microsoft has not - foolishly. Along with the `<sysexits.h>` this is an extremely handy API for proper command-line utilities.

If you only have a single `err()` call in the program, you can replace it with something like:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
...
    printf(stderr, "%s: select: %s\n", argv[0], strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
```

Comment: The call to `exit()` technically also requires `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: While it is extremely limited, VisualStudio does have `perror()`. If you can do without printing the program name `perror("select")` might suffice. It still requires a separate `exit(1)` and does not support printf style arguments the way `err()` does.